# Почему не срабатывает onItemLongClick в GridView?

Tags: android

Я только начинающий програмер, и скорее многого не понимаю, но я почитал на сайте и в интернете как при длительном нажатии на элемент gridview вызвать диалоговое окно с вариантами удали и еще что-то. Ну я для себя ради примера на варианты назначил hint. Но запустив приложение на эмуляторе и смартфоне ничего не происходит. Можете помочь?

вот класс в котором это не работает

```
import com.example.garderob.Clothes.NewMemoryActivity.NewMemoryActivity;
import com.example.garderob.R;
import com.example.garderob.db.MemoriesAdapter;
import com.example.garderob.db.MemoryDbHelper;

public class giletka extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MemoryDbHelper dbHelper;
    private GridView gridView;

    AlertDialog.Builder ad;
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_giletka);

        this.gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_grid_view);
        this.dbHelper = new MemoryDbHelper(this);
        this.gridView.setAdapter(new MemoriesAdapter(this, this.dbHelper.readAllMemories(),
                false));
        this.gridView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.activity_main_empty_view));

        gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                context = giletka.this;
                String title = "Выбор есть всегда";
                String message = "Что нужно сделать? Удалить вещь из гардероба или" +
                        "переместить вещь в раздел Утилизированное (раздел," +
                        "в котором хранятся вещи, которых у вас больше нет)";
                String button1String = "Удалить";
                String button2String = "Переместить в Утилизацию";

                ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                ad.setTitle(title);  // заголовок
                ad.setMessage(message); // сообщение
                ad.setPositiveButton(button1String, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Вы сделали правильный выбор",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                ad.setNegativeButton(button2String, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Возможно вы правы", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });
                return true;
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        ((CursorAdapter)gridView.getAdapter()).swapCursor(this.dbHelper.readAllMemories());
    }

    public void addNewMemory(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewMemoryActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

P.S кусочек где ничего не происходит

```
gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                context = giletka.this;
                String title = "Выбор есть всегда";
                String message = "Что нужно сделать? Удалить вещь из гардероба или" +
                        "переместить вещь в раздел Утилизированное (раздел," +
                        "в котором хранятся вещи, которых у вас больше нет)";
                String button1String = "Удалить";
                String button2String = "Переместить в Утилизацию";

                ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                ad.setTitle(title);  // заголовок
                ad.setMessage(message); // сообщение
                ad.setPositiveButton(button1String, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Вы сделали правильный выбор",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                ad.setNegativeButton(button2String, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Возможно вы правы", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });
                return true;
            }
        });
```

АДАПТЕР

```
package com.example.garderob.db;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.garderob.R;
import com.example.garderob.Clothes.model.Memory;

public class MemoriesAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public MemoriesAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean autoRequery) {
        super(context, cursor, autoRequery);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.memory_list_item, viewGroup, false);
        view.setTag(new ViewHolder(view));
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();

        Memory memory = new Memory(cursor);

        holder.titleTextView.setText(memory.getTitle());
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(memory.getImage());
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        final ImageView imageView;
        final TextView titleTextView;

        ViewHolder(View view) {
            imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_image_view);
            titleTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text_view);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите код адаптера. Внешний слушатель, вроде, не работает, если есть внутренний, назначаемый в адаптере.

Comment: Вы сможете помочь? Я немного не смыслю в этой проблеме. Зарание вам большое спасибо

Comment: Сложно понять почему у вас этот способ не работает. Проще всего его не использовать. А сделать так: в адаптере объявить интерфейс с методом `void onLongClick(Memory memory)`. В адаптере же создать переменную для этого интерфейса и сеттер к ней. В активити этот интерфейс реализовать, перенеся туда весь код, который у вас сейчас в onItemLongClick. После создания адаптера передайте ему через сеттер `this`. В адаптере в bindView повесьте на корневую разметку ячейки (`holder.titleTextView.getParent()`) слушатель долгого нажатия. В нём вызовите метод вашего интерфейса. Так будет правильнее.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо сейчас попробую, но если вам не трудно можете еще чуть-чуть поподробней рассказать что мне слелать(я понимаю что подробней не куда :\ ) Особенно можете пояснить вот эти строчки " В активити этот интерфейс реализовать, перенеся туда весь код, который у вас сейчас в onItemLongClick. После создания адаптера передайте ему через сеттер this. В адаптере в bindView повесьте на корневую разметку ячейки (holder.titleTextView.getParent()) слушатель долгого нажатия. В нём вызовите метод вашего интерфейса." А так преогроменное спасибо вы очень помогли

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы только настроили билдер диалога, но не создали и не вывели на экран сам диалог:

```
gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                context = giletka.this;
                String title = "Выбор есть всегда";
                String message = "Что нужно сделать? Удалить вещь из гардероба или" +
                        "переместить вещь в раздел Утилизированное (раздел," +
                        "в котором хранятся вещи, которых у вас больше нет)";
                String button1String = "Удалить";
                String button2String = "Переместить в Утилизацию";

                ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                ad.setTitle(title);  // заголовок
                ad.setMessage(message); // сообщение
                ad.setPositiveButton(button1String, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Вы сделали правильный выбор",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                ad.setNegativeButton(button2String, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Возможно вы правы", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });
                // создать и сразу же показать диалог
                ad.show();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Спасибо огроменное. А вы не могли бы еще помочь. Как мне на кнопку удалить, удалить элемент из gridView, а также из базы данных(sqLITE). А так вам преограменная благодарность